# Resize iframe until there is no scrollbar(fit content)

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, height

I have a basic layout table, with 4 rows. Header - Navigation - iframe - footer.
What I want to achieve is this:

Make the body height(in that case the table row the iframe is in) to fit the iframe content height. The iframe just loads some other html pages I've made.

So, the main index.html body scroller(overflow) will be used to scroll the iframe in that case.
Is that possible?

If it's not possible to increase the table row height to iframe content height I can just place it inside a div instead.

Comment: Is your iframe hosting site from within the same domain? EDIT: I just noticed you say that it is other pages of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do it in css/html.  You must use some javascript.

If this is your main.html...

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" border=1>
    <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Navigation</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <iframe src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

put this in the iframe.html...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var num=Math.ceil(Math.random()*50);
while(num-- > 0)
    document.write("num="+num+"<br/>");
window.parent.onload=function(){
    var parent=this.document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
    var elem=document.documentElement;
    parent.style.height=elem.scrollHeight+"px";
    parent.style.width=elem.scrollWidth+"px";
}
</script>
```

it writes a random number of lines to the document, then resizes itself based on its height.

http://frank.bridgewater.edu/test/iframeResize/

Comment: Hello, the script doesn't seem to work... I must be doing something wrong. It does add space but it doesn't fit the exact height of the iframe content. Note that the iframe height must change each time a different page is loaded. Also the num text is shown when viewing the site.

Comment: Are you still getting a scroll bar?  Here's the exact code http://frank.bridgewater.edu/test/iframeResize/ .  Reload the page over and over and you should see the iframe adjust its height automatically.

Comment: Well I think it's because of the script placement. I place it on bottom of the page. The iframe though is inside the table. There is no iframe.html on my project. So if I place this script on each external html it won't recognize the "IFRAME" part I suppose... Also I don't want to use random height number, it must be the height of the external html(which is different each time)